# Jquery open/close navigation

Tags: jquery, html

I building navigation list with open and close. But when I put *nav ul li.test a* to open hidden ul on click nothing happens. When I go with *nav ul li.test* without *a* hidden ul opens but link are unclickable, they keep doing function like they are parent ul. I think that is because .test is closing after hidden ul so they all are part od .test. So I go with *nav ul li.test a* but nothing happens. Here is a live example: [www.studioi.hr/index.php](http://www.studioi.hr/index.php)

```
   <nav> 
      <ul>
        <li class="test"><a href="#">Menu 1 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#11">Sub menu 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#12">Sub menu 2</a></li>   
             <li><a href="#13">Sub menu 3</a></li>                       
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="test"><a href="#">Menu 2 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#21">Sub menu 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#22">Sub menu 2</a></li>                       
           </ul>
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </nav>


jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('nav ul li.test a').click(function(){
        jQuery('nav ul ul').hide();
        jQuery('nav ul li a i').addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
        jQuery(this).children('ul').show();
        jQuery(this).find('a > i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
        return false;  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('nav ul li.test a').click(function(){
        jQuery('nav ul ul').hide();
        jQuery('nav ul li a i').addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
        jQuery(this).next('ul').show(); // change this
        jQuery(this).find('a > i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
        //add this statement
        if(jQuery(this).attr('href') != "#"){
          location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        }
        return false;  
    });
});
```

As i show you already changes it to your page :)

In your OP you try to find children ul in `a` element but there is none.

Comment: I change that, and now hidden list open but when I click on hidden list link don't take me to another page, hidden list just close, not open another page. I update www.studioi.hr/index.php with your code, so youc can look there.